# Is it possible to upload big file to wildfly chunk by chunk?

Tags: upload, wildfly, chunked

there, 
We have to upload big file to wildfly app server. The internet is not stable and may break from time to time. we need to transfer the big file chunk by chunk just like this post did: https://scribie.com/blog/2014/09/chunked-upload-with-nginx-and-nodejs/

I have googled for a while but not found clues about how to do on wildfly. Is there any example to kindly provide?

Thanks in advance.

Li